# Is there a way to find all images or media in a WordPress blog that aren't used in posts or pages?

Tags: images, wordpress

I have a WordPress travel blog that I have uploaded quite a lot of images to, and I'd like to extract a list of all of the images I have uploaded that, for some reason or another, aren't actually used in any posts or pages.

Is this possible, and how would I do it?

### How I think I got in this mess

Now, I know there's the 'Uploaded to' column in the Media Browser, but my understanding is that if I've uploaded an image while creating a post, and then just deleted the image link while editing the text, the image is still shown as 'Uploaded to' that post in the Media Browser.

Similarly, I have uploaded images using the Media Browser, and then tweaked an existing image link manually in the post, and these images show as 'Unattached' in said Media Browser.

### Bonus points..  :o)

Ideally, I'd like an easy way to delete these images from the site. This sounds like a great idea for a plugin but I haven't been able to find one, which makes me wonder if it's actually a feature of WordPress that I don't yet know about!

Comment: Is it a wordpress.com blog or self-hosted?

Comment: @Alex - it's self-hosted

Comment: Is there a reason your "Unattached" list in the Media browser (`example.com/wp-admin/upload.php?detached=1`) doesn't work?

Comment: @AlE. Yep, I've tested the two examples I gave in the question and they both result in incorrect status shown in the 'Unattached' column in the Media Browser

Answer (score -1):

if you have admin rights you can click add media, when the drop down appears click library.in the left top of screen there is a search tab put your name there, such as photos by your name. it should produce a list for you to browse. if you don't have any rights click on the site superviser name that should take to his page where you can leave him a message

Comment: Thanks @crowbar. I am a site admin, but how can I use the search tab to find images that aren't used in posts or pages? (can you add a little more detail please?)